# Do I need to physically crop my passport photo?

Tags: usa, passports, passport-renewals

When renewing my US passport, I need to send a 2" × 2" photo in to the State Dept. Is that just the size of the photo image or the size of the whole thing? That is to say, can I print my 2×2 photo on 3×5 paper and send that in with a white border?

Comment: 2" x 2" means square. Interesting, I thought passport picture are always rectangles. Are all US passport pictures square?

Comment: @pnuts because my snips might not be perfect enough? I dunno, I figure they have some cropping machine that trims it to the exact size?

Comment: Use a photo cutter... or paper cutter. They are about $12 at walmart...

Comment: I do not know about where you live, but here when you get passport photos taken in a shop they happily cut them to size for you, with a machine which will always get the size right.

Comment: @pnuts Not sure about the UK... but I have a mix of Canadian and US passports in my family... the Canadian ones are a LOT more ridged in various ways and a bit different. Example: You can't smile in a Canadian passport... and they seem a lot more picky about sizes and trimming.

Comment: I've done it with a paper cutter, no big deal.  We had 4 pictures printed on a 4x6 page, three cuts and we had 4 passport photos for a total cost of 29 cents.  If you can follow fairly simple directions and have a decent camera why pay the ripoff rates of the photo places?

Comment: wait, some countries let you smile?

Comment: @maplemale - You are not “allowed” to smile in US passports, either. It is an international ID standard. But, when I renewed my passport, the travel agency where I took my photo forgot. Since I was applying for visas for several different countries, I got several pictures taken. I had no issues with any of them in any country. When I got my passport renewed again, I used one of those photos that I had left over. Again, it passed unnoticed. Occasionally, a customs agent will be surprised by it and comment. Otherwise, no problems.

Comment: @DeanF. but the US was very slow in adopting that rule.  It only did so a few years ago.

Comment: @phoog - My last renewal was only a couple of years ago, after the no smile rule was applied here in the US. Yet, AI still got away with using a copy of my previous, smiling picture.

Answer (score 5):

The exact rules read "Photo should be 2”x2” (51 x 51 mm) with the head centered and sized between 1” and 1.4” (25 and 35 mm)."

This: https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/photos/photo-examples.html

Shows multiple examples of OK and not OK photos. I see no examples where a 2x2 photo on a larger media is OK. We personally cut our photos 2 x 2 and have never had an issue (very straight/even with a photo cutter)

Comment: ... which seems to tell us that the required tolerance on the cutting is 1 mm or better (otherwise they would probably have written 5 cm rather than 51 mm), but that it doesn't need to be better than 0.2 mm (since that is the difference between 2" and 51 mm).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think you're probably reading too much into that.

Answer (score 2):

2X2 is the size of the whole thing or paper. For exact measurements of the image itself, see:

https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/photos/photos.html

https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/photos/photo-composition-template.html

It answers all your questions.